# monitoring nexus repo

Tags: maven-2, nexus

Does anyone know of a nexus plugin or APIs that allows the monitoring of mvn artifacts deployments to a nexus repo? my issue is that developers are uploading all kind of jars to a nexus repo and i have no way of knowing who did what and why? How do i enforce a rule on them so that they have to type in a comment before uploading any jars to nexus? Is there a way of doing this in mvn/nexus???

Jenny

Answer (score 7):

There are several [RSS feeds](http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/using-sect-browsing-system.html) for broadcasting notifications of events within Nexus.

To monitor new deployments I'd suggest:

http://nexushost:8081/nexus/service/local/feeds/recentlyDeployedArtifacts

As for implementing deployment rules, your options are more limited. Nexus Professional has the ability to apply [rules](http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/ch09s06.html), however this only works as part of the build promotion functionality. Not sure how flexible this functionality is, and it's not part of the OSS edition.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the other answer there are a number of RSS feeds. In terms of who did what and tracking that even in the OSS version you can set up different users and roles. Just give each user their own username and password and only give deployment rights to the ones you trust to do the right thing..