# How to listen to local maven repo's changes?

Tags: maven, repository

I want to listen to changes of local maven repo. Then I could invoke some customized script.
My question is: is there any hook for maven to listen to whether maven is downloading new artifacts from remote repo?

Comment: The question is: Why do you need that? Nor that i know about something like this.

Comment: I need to recreate reponsitory.xml(jars index file) for geronimo server according to maven repo's changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest using the [Nexus](http://nexus.sonatype.org/) repository manager to store your artifacts.

The [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4382377/monitoring-nexus-repo/4392661#4392661) demonstrates how you can use the RSS feeds, provided by Nexus, to trigger actions in other systems.

Comment: thanks for your answer! But currently, we haven't use Nexus repo. Is there any way to do that in mvn? Like mvn plugin or hook API.

Comment: Sounds like you'd have to write a Maven plug-in to insert your check into the Maven build process. A plug-in solution would only work for your local project's build. It would be no use for other Maven jobs running against your local repository. It's unlikely you'll find a pre-existing plug-in. This definately sounds like an edge case requirement. Finally, installing and setting up Nexus is pretty easy. You'll learn more about how to use Maven.

Comment: yes, I think it's good solution. I do learn about how to use maven, I can use maven plugin to implement my own RepositoryListener to listen local repo's changes. Thanks Mark!