# Notifying when new artifact version in repository available?

Tags: notifications, continuous-integration, nexus, sonatype

is there a way to notify a CI system about a new published version of an artifact and trigger a build?

The scenario looks like that:

- Developer of team A working on component C commits changes
- CI is triggered, builds and runs tests
- After tests are passing the binaries are published to an artifact repo (Nexus)
- Another CI job receives this notification and triggers a build where other components + the new component C version are tested (integration tests).

Is there any plugin available on the market that supports such a notification mechanism? I haven't found yet such a tool for Nexus(Ivy)? The only thing I found is an Artifactory plugin from JFrog where you can publish from Teamcity directly.

Thanks,
Martin

Comment: possible duplicate of [monitoring nexus repo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4382377/monitoring-nexus-repo)

Comment: I am actually evaluating now Artifactory which is supported by TeamCity and Jenkins from where one can deploy binaries directly to the repo.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of anything pre-made that does this.  But you could easily write a small plugin that does this.  Have a look at the "virusscan" example here, it would just take a few small modifications to make it do what you want:

https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-example-plugins/

Answer (score 0):

Artifactory nowadays supports webhooks to achieve what I asked years ago: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Webhooks